# How can I determine the Simple Likelihood Ratio Test in the case of a Uniform(0,$\theta$) random variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

Suppose we are given independent random variables $X_{1},\dots,X_{n} \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,\theta)$. I'm having some trouble trying to find the most powerful test of size $\alpha$ of the hypothesis:
$$H_{0}: \theta = \theta_{0} = 20 \\ H_{1}: \theta=\theta_{1}>20$$
where $\theta_{1}$ is fixed. There are various similar questions on the forum, but none of the answers explain **why** what I'm doing is incorrect, or what it is exactly that I'm not understanding and why I should use the $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ statistic instead.  Here's my attempt:

So the Neyman-Pearson Lemma states that the Simple Likelihood Ratio Test (SLRT) is the most powerful sized $\alpha$ test between two simple hypotheses, which we have. So, I start by finding the likelihood ratio:

$$\lambda(X) = \frac{L(\theta_{1};X)}{L(\theta_{0};X)} = \frac{\theta_{1}^{-n}\mathbf{1}\{\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \leq \theta_{1}\}}{20^{-n}\mathbf{1}\{\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \leq 20\}}$$

where $\theta_{1} > 20$. In other words, $\lambda(X)$ is undefined if $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) <0$ or $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) > 20$. Otherwise, $\lambda(X) = \frac{\theta_{1}^{-n}}{20^{-n}}$ is constant. This is where I start to have some trouble.

The SLRT rejects $H_{0}$ iff $\lambda(X) \geq A_{\alpha}$, where $A_{\alpha}$ determines the size of the test $\alpha$. In other words, we choose $A_{\alpha}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\lambda(X) \geq A_{\alpha} | \theta = 20) = \alpha$. However under the null hypothesis, $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \leq 20$ almost surely, meaning that

$$\lambda(X) =^{H_{0}} (\frac{\theta_{1}}{20})^{-n}$$, which is a constant. So we can't find any constant $A_{\alpha}$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}(\lambda(X) \geq A_{\alpha} | \theta = 20) = \alpha$ since $\mathbb{P}(\lambda(X) \geq A_{\alpha}|H_{0})$ is either 1 or 0.

What is it that I'm doing that's wrong? I really want to understand **why** I'm making a mistake as well as what the mistake is. Or if I'm not making a mistake, I'd love to know why we can proceed using $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. There's a similar past paper question which writes the likelihood then just says that we can reformulate the problem using the quantiles of the $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ test statistic under $H_{0}$. If I accept that, then I can get the right answer but this leaves me with 2 questions:

1. What am I doing wrong initially when I compute the likelihood ratio under $H_{0}$?
2. Why can we switch to using the $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ statistic if under $H_{0}$ the likelihood ratio is constant? Why can we mathematically justify this? Usually, I'd compute the ratio, then rearrange to an inequality in terms of a test statistic whose distribution I know under $H_{0}$, but here $\mathrm{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is only prescribed in the indicator function, so this isn't possible.

Comment: This question is the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895801/likelihood-ratio-test-rejection-region-for-uniform-parameters - not a repost (the original was asked in 2014) but otherwise identical.

Comment: @jbowman I disagree. In that question, they state they are already given the test statistic and decision rule of the test. That isn't the case for me and it's one of the questions I have - why can max(X1,...,Xn) be used as a test statistic? This isn't answered in the link you posted.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Hint: $\max(X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: Fair point, I'd overlooked the $\max$ part of the question.  Once you have that, following kjetil's hint, though, I think you'll find the rest of it is in the link.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Again, I disagree with what you've said. First of all, this isn't actually homework - at no stage will I be handing a solution in for credit, but its an exercise in the lecture notes that I'm struggling with. Secondly, this is a variant of a similar past exam question; as stated in the question, I don't understand the solution.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thirdly, if you've read my question then its clear that I've stated what I understand thus far, what I've tried and where I'm stuck. I started by finding the SLR for 2 simple hypotheses and I found that under H_{0}, this is a constant. That's what I've tried & understand and that's where I'm stuck, because you can't find an A_{\alpha} st P[const > A_{\alpha} | H_{0}] = \alpha, since the probability is either 1 or 0. How do I proceed from here? In the similar past exam question, they write the likelihood ratio and then proceed using max(X1,...,Xn). Why?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Right, so if that's a sufficient statistic, then by Fisher Neyman, the likelihood can be split into a term depending only on the data h(x) and a term g(T(x);theta). In the likelihood ratio, the h(x) term cancels. We reject H_{0} iff LR(T(X);theta) >= const. So if the LR is monotonically increasing in T(X), then an equivalent test is rejecting H_{0} iff T(X) >= const2, for some const2 that's determined by the density of T(X). Is that all correct? In this case, the LR is monotonically increasing only over [0,20], so does this thinking still apply?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Is all that correct?